# what will happen if we close a closed socket

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I wonder what will happen if we close a closed socket or a non-existing socket?
Will the exception affect the other sockets which are sending/receiving packets?

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I mean I know what it will return from close or shutdown function and what the return means, but I don't know what it affects the existing sockets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Potentially, yes. If you call close on a random integer which used to be an fd, you might break some other part of your code that's just opened another connection that got given the same fd number. Therefore, you should never double-close an fd: although it's perfectly safe from the kernel's point of view (you harmlessly get EBADF), it can seriously mess up your application.

Answer (score 1):

Or close(): per `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/close.html`

will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EBADF`. The fildes argument is not a valid file descriptor.

Comment: Is there any recommended way to avoid double-close FD, especially in multi-thread cases? I often deal this with a global variable, but not sure if any nice way.